# Is it possible to add a callback method in the backend to perform once a query finishes?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, amazon-sns, cube.js

I'm setting up a service that will email a user the data generated by a Cubejs query. I'd like to have Cubejs notify the email-sending service (perhaps through SNS) that new data is available for sending: Is this possible? Are there better options for allowing asynchronous access to query results?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could look into `WebSocketTransport`, part of the [real-time data fetch](https://cube.dev/docs/real-time-data-fetch) mechanism?